# What am I doing wrong with ecommerce part of Google Analytics (analytics.js)?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

I need your help with Google Analytics (analytics.js). I have a first general part in the head section which works fine:

```
<script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
             m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'UA-72717911-1', 'auto');
              ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

However when I add to the regular body section of "success" page the following part to keep tracking of transactions, I do not receive it in google analytics. I'm not JS specialist at all, so solution could be quite simple, however I do not see any error in debug tools and even special google plugin for chrome looks normal.

```
<script>
    ga('require', 'ecommerce');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '001',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
    'affiliation': 'trendybox.com.ua',   // Affiliation or store name.
    'revenue': '500',               // Grand Total.
    'shipping': '0',                  // Shipping.
    'tax': '0'                     // Tax.
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '" . $order_id . "',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'product1',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD00111',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Cosmetics',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '500',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>"
```

Comment: Under the setting in GA is "Enable Ecommerce" turn ON?

Comment: As per my comment to nyuens answer, also check that "Enhanced Ecommerce Settings" is turned to "off" since the standard tracking code will not work with EEC enabled.

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff, I believe standard ecommerce will still work even if EE is enabled in the settings. In my answer, I captured my settings, yet (some of) the transaction details still appeared in my reports.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine, and I was able to copy and paste it into my site and see the transaction data. Just make sure that the Ecommerce is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be "check that EEC is off" ? The example in the original post is not EEC syntax, it's standard e-commerce tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers. It was just a delay - google analytics required several days to display ecommerce info (more then 3 days in my case).